# How to interpolate cumulative histogram data?

Tags: python, matplotlib, scipy, histogram, interpolation

I have got a set of histograms from numpy.histogram:

```
probas, years = zip(*[np.histogram(r, bins= bin_values)  for r in results])
```

results is an array of shape`(9, 10000)` The bin values are the years from `2029` and `2066`. The `probas` array has a shape `(9,37)` and the `years` array `(9,38)`. So `years[:,:-1]` has a shape of `(9,37)`.

I can obtaint he cumulative histogram data using:

```
probas = np.cumsum(probas, axis=1)
```

I can then normalize it to [0,1]:

```
probas = np.asarray(probas)
probas = probas/np.max(probas, axis = 0)
```

I then try and interpolate that cumulative distribution using scipy:

```
inverse_pdfs = [scipy.interpolate.interp1d(probas[i], years[i,:-1]) for i in range(probas.shape[0])]
```

When I plot the third histogram of the data set as a `plt.plot()` and that from the `inverse_pdfs` using:

```
i = 2
plt.plot(years[i,:-1], probas[i], color="orange")
probability_range = np.arange(0.,1.01,0.01)
plt.plot([inverse_pdfs[i](p) for p in probability_range], probability_range, color="blue")
```

I obtain:

[image]

As you can see the match is pretty good for most of the years after 2042, but before that it is very bad.

Any suggestion on how to improve that match, or where the problem comes from, would be very welcome.

For information, the data used to train the interpolator on the third histogram are:

```
years[2,:-1]: [2029. 2030. 2031. 2032. 2033. 2034. 2035. 2036. 2037. 2038. 2039. 2040.
 2041. 2042. 2043. 2044. 2045. 2046. 2047. 2048. 2049. 2050. 2051. 2052.
 2053. 2054. 2055. 2056. 2057. 2058. 2059. 2060. 2061. 2062. 2063. 2064.
 2065.]

probas[2]:[0.     0.     0.     0.     0.     0.     0.     0.     0.     0.
 0.     0.     0.     0.0916 0.2968 0.4888 0.6666 0.8335 0.9683 1.
 1.     1.     1.     1.     1.     1.     1.     1.     1.     1.
 1.     1.     1.     1.     1.     1.     1.    ]
```